# Route Not Found For GET / - Can't serve default index.html

Tags: c#, rest, grapevine

I have setup several routes for a REST api using Grapevine, for a small webserver in a desktop app.  The API works fine, and other static files work fine, but I can't get the router to route an empty url: http://:port/ to the root index.html file in the prescribed folder.

Web is a folder in the exe path, containing index.html, and test.html.

I can serve http://xxx:8080/test.html just fine. 
http://xxx:8080/ gives "Route Not Found For GET /"

Webserver setup:

```
        ServerSettings settings = new ServerSettings()
        {
            Host = "*",
            Port = "8080",
            PublicFolder = new PublicFolder("Web")                
        };

        server = new RestServer(settings);
        server.Start();
```

Routes:

```cs
    [RestResource]
    public class WebRequestHandler
    {
        [RestRoute(HttpMethod = HttpMethod.GET, PathInfo = "/api/v1/live")]
        public IHttpContext Live(IHttpContext context)
        {
            snip
            return context;
        }

        [RestRoute(HttpMethod = HttpMethod.GET, PathInfo = "/api/v1/cmd1/[id]")]
        public IHttpContext Cmd1(IHttpContext context)
        {
            return context;
        }

        [RestRoute(HttpMethod = HttpMethod.GET, PathInfo = "/api/v1/cmd2/[id]")]
        public IHttpContext Cmd2(IHttpContext context)
        {
            snip
            return context;
        }

        [RestRoute(HttpMethod = HttpMethod.GET, PathInfo = "/api/v1/cmd3/[id]")]
        public IHttpContext Cmd3(IHttpContext context)
        {
            snip
            return context;
        }


    }
```

index.html needs to serve when the root url is requested.

Comment: show your route definition for rest api

Comment: added route defs

Comment: Which version of Grapevine are you using?

Comment: @ScottOffen  4.1.1 nuget and githib 31/5/19  I posted an answer where I hacked a workaround.  it seamed to be that chrome would send the url as '/' and the directly listing had empty key for the root folder. so it wouldn't match '/' to index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

add a route that handles '/' and return the file manually.

many thanks for your help.  I can now use the Nuget package and not worry about a hacked local copy of the lib.

Fantastic library BTW, I nearly dropped using it because the examples and wiki are so sparse I couldn't figure anything out.  Very glad I persevered.  Much simpler than everything else I saw (after figuring it out).

```
        [RestRoute(HttpMethod = HttpMethod.GET, PathInfo = "/")]
        public IHttpContext Root(IHttpContext context)
        {
            var filepath = Path.Combine(context.Server.PublicFolder.FolderPath, 
                                        context.Server.PublicFolder.IndexFileName);

            var lastModified = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(filepath).ToString("R");
            context.Response.AddHeader("Last-Modified", lastModified);

            if (context.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("If-Modified-Since"))
            {
                if (context.Request.Headers["If-Modified-Since"].Equals(lastModified))
                {
                    context.Response.SendResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotModified);
                    return context;
                }
            }

            context.Response.ContentType = ContentType.DEFAULT.FromExtension(filepath);
            context.Response.SendResponse(new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open));

            return context;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, this way felt clunky to me, so I left it out of my (now deleted) answer. I do need to finish the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem with latest nuget 4.1.1?  and github as of 31/5/19

I modified the lib for this change here:

```
protected void AddToDirectoryList(string fullPath)
        {
            DirectoryList[CreateDirectoryListKey(fullPath)] = fullPath;
            if (fullPath.EndsWith($"\\{_indexFileName}"))
            {
                DirectoryList[CreateDirectoryListKey(fullPath.Replace($"\\{_indexFileName}", ""))] = fullPath;
+++             DirectoryList["/"] = fullPath;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I removed my answer as it was completely inaccurate (as you pointed out). If you want to submit an issue, I can add a feature that would handle this.

Comment: Thanks I will do so it can be tracked.  Thanks for your Help.